# Why components become big when I insert JList into dialog with GridLayout?

Tags: java, swing, jlist

If I use JList my JDialog becomes very large and JTextFields are resized themselves. But if I don't use JList all is ok.

To see my big buttons and textfields please run this demo:

```
package demo;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class AddInventoryDialog extends JDialog {

    private static AddInventoryDialog dialog;

    private AddInventoryDialog() {
        super(null, "Add inventory", ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        JPanel contentPane = (JPanel) super.getContentPane();
        contentPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
        super.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 20));
        super.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(10, 2, 10, 5));

        JLabel nameLabel = new JLabel("Name");
        JLabel sizeLabel = new JLabel("Size");
        JLabel brandLabel = new JLabel("Brand");
        JLabel patternLabel = new JLabel("Pattern");
        JLabel colorLabel = new JLabel("Color");
        JLabel boughtLabel = new JLabel("Bought date(dd MM yyyy)");
        JLabel lastWashedLabel = new JLabel("Last washed(dd MM yyyy)");
        JLabel seasonLabel = new JLabel("Season");
        JLabel categoryLabel = new JLabel("Category");

        final JTextField nameField = new JTextField();
        final JTextField sizeField = new JTextField();
        final JTextField brandField = new JTextField();
        final JTextField patternField = new JTextField();
        final JTextField colorField = new JTextField();
        final JTextField boughtField = new JTextField();
        final JTextField lastWashedField = new JTextField();
        final JList<String> categoryField = new JList<>(new String[] { "ietm1", "ietm1", "ietm1", "ietm1" });

        panel.add(nameLabel);
        panel.add(nameField);
        panel.add(sizeLabel);
        panel.add(sizeField);
        panel.add(brandLabel);
        panel.add(brandField);
        panel.add(patternLabel);
        panel.add(patternField);
        panel.add(colorLabel);
        panel.add(colorField);
        panel.add(boughtLabel);
        panel.add(boughtField);
        panel.add(lastWashedLabel);
        panel.add(lastWashedField);
        panel.add(categoryLabel);
        panel.add(categoryField);

        final JButton cancelButton = new JButton("Cancel");
        final JButton okButton = new JButton("OK");
        panel.add(cancelButton);
        panel.add(okButton);

        contentPane.add(new JLabel("Add inventory"), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        contentPane.add(panel);

        super.pack();
    }

    public static void undisplay() {
        getInstance().dispose();
    }

    public static void display() {
        getInstance().setVisible(true);
    }

    public static AddInventoryDialog getInstance() {
        if (dialog == null) {
            dialog = new AddInventoryDialog();
        }
        return dialog;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        getInstance().setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

I tried to embed JList into JScrollPane but it didn;t help.

How to make JTextFields and JButtons to have their natural size(not so big)?

Thank you!

Comment: are you using netbeans or some kind of IDE to generate GUI?

Comment: That's the nature of GridLayout. Components are made equal in size. The size the being that of the largest component. You may want to use a different layout manager or a combination of them using nested panels.

Comment: Use the GridBagLayout Luke

Comment: Problems with layout may be connected with your chosen layout manager. I would advise you read up the javadocs on the classes you use.

Answer (score 1):

In GridLayout all components are given equal size. Try another layout manager, for example `GridBagLayout`

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class AddInventoryDialog extends JDialog {

    private static AddInventoryDialog dialog;

    private void addLabeledField(JLabel label, JComponent field, JPanel panel,
            GridBagConstraints c) {

        c.gridx = 0;
        panel.add(label, c);
        c.gridx++;
        panel.add(field, c);
        c.gridy++;
    }

    private AddInventoryDialog() {
        super(null, "Add inventory", ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        JPanel contentPane = (JPanel) super.getContentPane();
        contentPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
        super.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 20));
        super.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        // panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(10, 2, 10, 5));
        panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.gridy = 0;

        JLabel nameLabel = new JLabel("Name");
        JLabel sizeLabel = new JLabel("Size");
        JLabel brandLabel = new JLabel("Brand");
        JLabel patternLabel = new JLabel("Pattern");
        JLabel colorLabel = new JLabel("Color");
        JLabel boughtLabel = new JLabel("Bought date(dd MM yyyy)");
        JLabel lastWashedLabel = new JLabel("Last washed(dd MM yyyy)");
        JLabel seasonLabel = new JLabel("Season");
        JLabel categoryLabel = new JLabel("Category");

        final JTextField nameField = new JTextField();
        final JTextField sizeField = new JTextField();
        final JTextField brandField = new JTextField();
        final JTextField patternField = new JTextField();
        final JTextField colorField = new JTextField();
        final JTextField boughtField = new JTextField();
        final JTextField lastWashedField = new JTextField();
        final JList<String> categoryField = new JList<String>(new String[] {
                "ietm1", "ietm1", "ietm1", "ietm1" });

        addLabeledField(nameLabel, nameField, panel, c);
        addLabeledField(sizeLabel, sizeField, panel, c);
        addLabeledField(brandLabel, brandField, panel, c);
        addLabeledField(patternLabel, patternField, panel, c);
        addLabeledField(colorLabel, colorField, panel, c);
        addLabeledField(boughtLabel, boughtField, panel, c);
        addLabeledField(lastWashedLabel, lastWashedField, panel, c);

        addLabeledField(categoryLabel, categoryField, panel, c);

        final JButton cancelButton = new JButton("Cancel");
        final JButton okButton = new JButton("OK");
        c.gridx = 0;
        panel.add(cancelButton, c);
        c.gridx++;
        panel.add(okButton, c);

        contentPane.add(new JLabel("Add inventory"), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        contentPane.add(panel);

        super.pack();
    }

    public static void undisplay() {
        getInstance().dispose();
    }

    public static void display() {
        getInstance().setVisible(true);
    }

    public static AddInventoryDialog getInstance() {
        if (dialog == null) {
            dialog = new AddInventoryDialog();
        }
        return dialog;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        getInstance().setVisible(true);
    }
}
```